# Need help using "if" and "empty" and "echo" Magento

Tags: magento, echo

Sorry I'm only self taught but having trouble with something.

I currently have a custom attribute that I'd like to echo a price only if the attribute has no value.  This is what I have right now but it calls both at the moment.  This is for the product list.phtml page. Have been experimenting for the past 3 hours and can't figure how to do it.

```
<div class="product-pricerange" id="product-pricerange">
   <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('pricerange')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) ?>
</div>

   <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

Thanks in advance as any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by wrapping it up in an IF statement a bit like so:

```
<div class="product-pricerange" id="product-pricerange">
    <?php if(!$_product->getData("your_attrubute")):?>
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly. the getData was the key.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use hasData() functionnality

```
<div class="product-pricerange" id="product-pricerange">
  <?php if($_product->hasPricerange()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
  <?php endif;?>
</div>
```